# How can I get wine to recognize ntdll.so?

Tags: wine

Wine suddenly stopped working entirely, with every command resulting in the message `wine: could not load ntdll.so: /usr/libexec/wine/../../lib32/wine/i386-unix/ntdll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. This path does not exist anymore, so I found the location of `ntdll.so` at `/lib/wine/x86_64-unix/` and modified my command to run wine to:
`WINEDLLPATH=/usr/lib/wine/x86_64-unix wine64 file.exe`. The error changes to `wine: could not load ntdll.so: /usr/lib/wine/x86_64-unix/ntdll.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64`. What does this error  mean and how can I fix it?

My system is a x86_64 machine and I am running a 64 bit .exe file.

Answer (score 1):

I think this needs the `x86_64` version of the `ntdll.so` and that's why it issues the error

```
wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

I had the same error and downgrading to wine 5.0.2 solved it.